# How do I align the tittle and the image in a button?

Tags: xml, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I want my button to look like this:

[image: I want my button to look like this]

This is my current code :

```
<Button id="btn_login" title="SIGN IN" image="/images/signin-icon.png"></Button>
```

But what I am getting is that the arrow is at the far left, and the title is slightly to the right from the center. Looks like the image is taking up the space from the left.

How can I align them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is not use a button, but a regular view. Like this:

```
<View id="btn_login">
    <View id="buttonWrapper">
        <Label id="signIn" />
        <ImageView id="signInImage" />
    </View>
</View>
```

Then in tss:

```
"#btn_login": {
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
}

"#buttonWrapper" :{
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    layout: 'horizontal'
}

"#signIn": {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    color: "#ffffff"
}

"#signInImage: {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE
}
```

I made the `buttonWrapper` to position both elements at the same time, and also allow it to be centered. Because I do not specify `left` and `right` property it will center automatically.

`layout` property will make sure elements are positioned next to each other, and not on top of each other.

Having a width of `Ti.UI.SIZE` will automatically size it based on content.

Now... it will not look exactly like your image, but it will be close. From there on play with some fonts and positioning of the image for example and it should work great!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to write much code, then you can use **[Font Awesome long arrow right icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/long-arrow-right/)**  with button title. The reason to use font is that you can get Material theme touch-flow animation on Android buttons.

See below example on how to do this:

***index.xml***

```
<Button class="fa" title="    SIGN IN \uf178   " />
```

***index.tss***

```
".fa" : {
    font : { fontFamily : 'fontawesome',fontSize : 19 }  // you can change the font size here
}
```

Download the **[fontawesome.ttf file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hq857p1v6m19nad/fontawesome.ttf?dl=0)**

Place this **.ttf** file in app->assets->fonts folder, if fonts folder is not there, then create it and then place the file. See below image of placing the file correctly.

[image]

Your button should look like this (except green background which comes from theme file)[image]:

You can add more spaces in between the unicode of arrow icon and SIGN IN text.